# What is the so-called "GUDAGUDA ship" involving Oda Nobunaga and Okita Souji?

Tags: culture, type-moon, fate-grand-order

I was reading [this piece of short comic remake titled "How you play it" illustrated by Kawacy](https://kawacy.deviantart.com/art/How-you-play-it-705038217) and it says

> Oda Nobunaga and Okita Souji from Fate/Grand Order
>
> a.k.a the GUDAGUDA ship.

So I search about it, it seems like an [event from Fate/Grand Order called GUDAGUDA Honnouji Event](http://fategrandorder.wikia.com/wiki/GUDAGUDA_Honnouji_Event). From [here](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=343&element_id=6569), I know gudaguda (ぐだぐだ) mean exhausted; tired. But the event summery says

> Something like a "GUDAGUDA Honnouji" suddenly appeared in Chaldea, and Oda Nobunaga is ready for action!

which suggests it's an object rather than a state

So what is GUDAGUDA exactly in relation to Fate/GO? And why did the Oda Nobunaga and Okita Souji pairing get called GUDAGUDA ship? I tried to Google GUDAGUDA ship and I got lot of Oda Nobunaga and Okita Souji pairing so it's not something only from Kawacy above

---

Note: I have zero knowledge of Japanese language and I never play Fate/GO

Comment: i am shamed! i was beaten to posting this

Comment: [Direct translations](https://jisho.org/search/gudaguda) questions are off-topic, per [this discussion](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/79/63). If you would like to ask a Japanese language question in the context of a specific series (e.g., What does Osakabehime's designation as a "hikikomori" have to do with the origami bats she uses? [tag:fate-grand-order]), it might be more on-topic.

Comment: @кяαzєя I never ask for direct translate, I know (from Google) GUDAGUDA mean "exhausted"; "tired" but what does it have to do in Fate/GO and why does the pairing called as such

Comment: Voted to reopen, though I have a misunderstanding about GUDAGUDA ship at first. Note there are *guda-ko* and *guda-o* in FGO, but it's not about them. In this case, it's more about [the main characters from GUDAGUDA event](http://fate-go.us/gudao/gudao01.html).

Comment: Okita and Nobu predate FGO and are from Koha Ace, a Typemoon fate parody manga. [Shipping characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipping_(fandom)) from the same series is hardly anything new.

Comment: @кяαzєя true but from my current understanding it's the naming of the ship is odd. like in fandom you have the obvious ones like MadoHomu, and NanoFate but even when they aren't obvious like with RWBY's Monochrome and Bumblebee it has some relation back to the characters in the ship (Monochrome = Weiss (White) x Blake (Black), Bumblebee = Blake (Black) x Yang (Yellow)). previous research shows that GUDAGUDA is a F/GO Event but this wouldn't explain why the fandom has taken it as a ship name (especially when Nobunaga and Okita predate the event)

Comment: I'm actually doubting if the term "GUDAGUDA ship" is not originated by Kawacy himself. Googling that returns mostly his images on DA, or Tumblr that refers to his DA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago, there was this parody manga written by Keikenchi called Koha-Ace, featuring Kohaku from Tsukihime as an main character of sorts, along with several characters of the Nasuverse. Although it's a joke-series, it's still considered official, some of it's segments were part of the Carnival Phantasm animation.

One of the stories that ran in this manga was Fate/KOHA-ACE, an alternate Third Holy Grail War, where Oda Nobunaga (Demon Archer) and Okita Souji (Sakura Saber) were summoned.

After the mobile app based on the Nasuverse, Fate/Grand Order, was announced, Keikenchi was asked to author a short series to be released on the game's website some time before the game even released. It was supposed to be a showcase of the servants that would be available on the game, though it kind of degenerated into random shaenaenigans. The web series was titled Fate/GUDAGUDA Order, and the MCs of sorts were Nobunaga and Okita, and they ended up being shipped by the fandom. Eventually, they actually made it to the game during an event around 4-5 months after the game was released, which was called the GUDAGUDA Honnouji event.

You can legally read this manga on the F/GO (US) site [here](http://fate-go.us/gudao/).